# How to resolve configuration error generated by IIS?

Tags: angular, iis

I am deploying my angular application on IIS manager.
I build my application using this command `ng build  --prod --base-href /home/`
And data generated on `dist` folder, I added that folder on IIS application.
This is the files generated on dist folder

[image]

But while calling this endpoint, I am getting this error

[image]

What changes should I make to deploy my angular application on IIS?

Comment: try to add iis_iusrs and iusr full user permission to the site root folder

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems the problem is a mismatch between your `--base-href` and the actual location of the Angular App.

The Path you provide must be the Path from your root folder to your Angular Application, or to be more precise, the Path from your root folder to your index.html and subsequently to all other Files needed.

Imagine the following:
If your root folder is `/var/www/public_html` or `C:\inetpub\wwwroot` and you place your Angular app there, then your `--base-href` is just a single `/`.

If you place your Angular App in `/var/www/public_html/home` or `C:\inetpub\wwwroot\home` than your `--base-href` is just a single `/home`.

If you place your dist Folder in there your Path would be `/var/www/public_html/home/dist` or `C:\inetpub\wwwroot\home\dist` and therefore the `--base-href` must be `--base-href /home/dist`.

It all depends where your Root folder and your Angular App is located on your Filesystem.

Depending on this Configuration, the Angular App will be available at `http://my-domain.tld + <baseHref>`.
So either `http://my-domain.tld/` or `http://my-domain.tld/home`

**What is the Root Folder?**

The Root Folder is the folder, where all the files are you get served if you browse to `http://my-domain.tld`

Comment: I did the same, then After I am getting this error Configuration Error
Description: An error occurred during the processing of a configuration file required to service this request. Please review the specific error details below and modify your configuration file appropriately.

Parser Error Message: An error occurred loading a configuration file: Failed to start monitoring changes to 'C:\Users\D\Desktop\optimix' because access is denied.

Comment: It is asking for web.config file
Source File: C:\Users\D\Desktop\optimix\web.config    Line: 0
Exception Details: System.Web.HttpException: Failed to start monitoring changes to 'C:\Users\D\Desktop\optimix' because access is denied.

Comment: Seems like you do not have the access Rights to the Service or the Folder. Did you check that you actually can read/write to that folder?